# How does a server know that it recieved an SSL close notify?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I will use materials from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.9/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.09/gtps5/s5sslsf.html) for it helps to clarify the question.

The image below represents a SSL session flow

[image]

The description for step `7` states:

> When either the client or the server is ready to end the connection,
>   both the client and the server issue the SSL_shutdown() function to
>   indicate that the SSL connection is ending normally. This causes an
>   SSL record whose type is alert to flow. For this, the type of alert is
>   close notify, which means the SSL session is ending.

Given that the server is just and echo server with SSL that has a `while(1)` inside which it reads and writes the same back to the client.

What openSSL command needs to be run on the server so that it understands that the client sent a `close notify` and that it isn't just some message it should echo?

In the quote how does one express `both the client and the server issue the SSL_shutdown()` with code? Would expect either one to send a `close notify` and the other to respond as a reaction to it.

Answer (score 2):

`close_notify` manifests itself to the recipient as end of stream when reading, same as `read()` returning 0 on a C plaintext socket.